# jQuery cannot change bootstrap's data-placement

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've found a bug.
jQuery cannot seem to change the data-placement of its popovers after the HTML has been rendered.

Example time:

```
   $('[data-toggle=popover],[rel=popover]').popover();

 <? if (isset($labels) && $labels): ?>
  <div id="<?= $id ?>" class="product-labels leak-image-click">
    <? foreach($labels as $label): ?>
      <a class="product-label cursor-pointer" data-label="<?= $label ?>" tabindex="0" data-toggle="popover"  role="button" data-trigger="focus" <?= $label == "soldout" ? "data-soldout-target='".$soldout."'" : "" ?>>
      </a>
    <? endforeach ?>
  </div>
<? endif ?>

labels.init = function(id) {

  $('#' + id).children(".product-label").each( function() {   
    var labelName = $(this).data("label"),
        placement = meventi.getViewSize() == "xs" ? "right" : "top",
        options = {
          "placement": "top"
        };
    $(this).attr("data-content", labels.descriptions[$(this).data("label")]);

    $(this).addClass("product-label-" + labelName );
    $(this).attr("data-placement", "left");
    $(this).popover(options).popover("show");

    $(this).click(function(e){
      $(e.target).popover("show");
    });
  });
};
```

Then i use jQuery to change data-placement when the page loads.
    `append_slot("js")` is from the Symfony framework.

```
    <? append_slot("js") ?>

  meventi.labels.init("<?= $id ?>");
<? end_slot() ?>
```

And when looking at the HTML element in the Chrome Developer tools, I can see that the element reads `data-placement="top"`, however the popover still appears on the left like it was originally set

Comment: so you're injecting pure JS into pure PHP, ok. That's a syntax error right off the bat.

Comment: Have you tried `.data("placement", "top");` ?

Comment: I'm injecting jQuery into a 'js' slot in php. Originally i had a labels.init() with this functionality inside, but I took this out in this example for simplicities sake.

Comment: funny what a simple `.` will do to someone's day. I've been there before.

Comment: @user887675 .data("placement", "top") doesnt change the HTML at all, but   attr("data-placement", "top"); will at least display the data-placement change even though the popover still appears on the left.

Comment: @Fred-ii- There is no syntax error. Where are you implying the `.` should be placed?

Comment: see the answers given below. `$("doge")` to `$(".doge")`

Comment: The answer is not adding a . to the class 'doge' although thank you for finding this :). This was an error on my end. I simplified the original code quickly and so this error was made. The problem still remains

Comment: Ok, now that you've updated your post; are short tags enabled? If not, then change all instances of `<?` to `<?php`. Or, see the new answer.

Comment: short tags are enabled

Comment: could be a CSS related issue in your bootstrap css files? you also tagged as PHP, so check for errors with error reporting. I'm out of ideas here.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is being closed because it is 'off-topic'. It is very much on the topic stated in the title.

Comment: are you using Symfony by any chance? I couldn't find anything related to jQuery for append_slot() and end_slot(), and it appears to be that; Symfony, unless they're custom functions. If you want to append in jQuery and far as I know, it's `.append()`. You may have to show more code for your question, because as it stands, it looks to be next to unanswerable in its present state. Either post more code, and/or make a jsfiddle.

Comment: @Fred-ii- We use Symfony in my company but I havent worked with it myself. I will post more code in just a moment.

Comment: Dont you also need a `data-toggle="popover"` so BS/JS knows what it is dealing with?

Comment: `data-toggle="popover"` is in the most recent update, and the popover does appear, but it is placed to the default side

Comment: @RiggsFolly I discovered that placing `data-toggle="popover"` is not necessary if you do something like `var options = {
          "placement": "top",
          "title", : meventi.labels.descriptions[$(this).data("label")][0],
          "content": meventi.labels.descriptions[$(this).data("label")][1],
          "trigger": "focus"
        };` and then calling `$(this).popover(options);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

Globally initiating all popovers with `$('[data-toggle=popover],[rel=popover]').popover();` must be called **after** declaring the data-placement `$(this).attr("data-placement", "left");`

Changing the data-content like `meventi.labels.descriptions[$(this).data("label")]);` and other datas can be called after `$('[data-toggle=popover],[rel=popover]').popover();`

Answer (score 0):

"doge" is not finding the class, you need ".doge".

Try changing

```
  $("doge").attr("data-placement", "top");
```

to

```
  $(".doge").attr("data-placement", "top");
```

Comment: The `.` was not the cause, but thank you for this find. My question states that the data-placement was changed in the html when the page loaded but the popover still was created in the direction it was originally set, "left"

Answer (score 0):

Of course it doesn't work you have a typo and aren't attaching a handler.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".doge").attr("data-placement", "top");
});
```

Comment: I'd take out the *"Try something like:"* ;-) and let's all hope it was a missing dot and not a bad paste.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I agree. :)

Comment: the OP just updated their original post with the missing dot. Now, why did my *Spidey sense* tingle?

Comment: The `.` was not the cause. My question states that the data-placement **was** changed in the html when the page loaded but the popover still was created in the direction it was originally set, "left"

Comment: `$(".doge").attr("data-placement", "top");` has already been attempted. As ive stated multiple times, the typo only relates to the writing of this question and the data-placement IS changing in the HTML element when the page loads. If I made a typo or was not attaching a handler, this would not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can also edit data attributes via the jQuery [data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method:

```
 $(".doge").data("placement", "top");
```

Comment: .data("placement", "top") doesnt change the HTML at all, but attr("data-placement", "top"); will at least display the data-placement change even though the popover still appears on the left.